# Proof about maximum value of a function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

So I was thinking about how to prove the following: Given a real valued function of one variable on the real axis, say $f(x)$, with a unique global maximum at $x_{0}$ such that $\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)=f(x_{0})$, prove that
\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)=\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(ax+b).
\end{equation}

After a bit of thought I began to wonder about a more general case:
\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)=\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(g(x)).
\end{equation}

What restrictions must be placed on $g(x)$ for this condition to be true in general?  Is there a proof for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All what you need is that $x_0\in g(\Bbb R)$.

That is,
$$\max_{x\in\Bbb R}f(x)=\max_{x\in\Bbb R}f(g(x))\iff \exists x_1\in\Bbb R:g(x_1)=x_0$$

Or, alternatively,
 $$\max_{x\in\Bbb R}f(x)=\max_{x\in\Bbb R}f(g(x))\iff \exists x_1\in\Bbb R:g(x_1)\in f^{-1}(\{\max_{x\in\Bbb R}f(x)\})$$
condition that works even if $f$ reaches its maximum more than once.

Comment: If I wanted to generalize this a bit would it be sufficient/correct to write: Let $f,g$ be real valued functions of a single variable. If the maximum of $f$ exists, then $g[Y]=X\implies \max_{x\in X}f(x)=\max_{y\in Y}f(g(y))$.

Answer (score 4):

you need that $$\exists y$$ such that $$g(y)=x_0 $$

Notably that's always true when $g(x)$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

The only condition required is that $Image (g) = \mathbb R$.  Then  $\max_{x\in \mathbb R}f(g(x)) = \max_{x \in Image(g)}f(x)
=\max_{x\in \mathbb R} f(x)$.

Otherwise the condition is $\max_{x\in \mathbb R}f(g(x)) = \max_{x \in Image(g)}f(x) \le \max_{x\in \mathbb R}f(x)$.

So the condition is: $g$ must be surjective.

This is a proof if you assume that for $A \subset B$ then $\max A \le \max B$ which is trivial to prove by definitions.

Actually that is a *sufficient* but not *necessary* condition.  All we need is that $g$ is such that there is an $a\in Image(g)$ so that $f(a) = \max f(x)$.  That will *have* to happen if $g$ is surjective.  It doesnt necessarily have to happen if $g$ is not but it could happen.  If it doesnt happen then $\max f(g(x)) < \max f(x)$.

Note: ALL of this is assuming $\max_{x \in \mathbb R} f(x)$ and $\max_{x \in Image(g)}f(x)$ exist.  Which they need not do.  Even if $f$ is bounded above a maximum element need not exist.